# Displaying Calculations from Controller In View blade Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i am building an asset management system.I would like to have the following calculations done in the controller to be displayed in the view.

```
  public function depreciation()
    {

    $assets = Asset::all();

        $price = DB::table('assets')
            ->where('category_id', 1)
            ->sum('purchase_price');
        $dep = $price * 0.3333;
        $netprice = $price - $dep;

        return $netprice;

        return view('admin.assets.index')->with(['price','dep', 'netprice' => $netprice]);


}
```

My Route

```
    Route::post('assets_depreciation', ['uses' => 'Admin\AssetsController@depreciation', 'as' => 'assets.depreciation']);
```

My View

```
 <tbody>
                @if (count($assets) > 0)
                    @foreach ($assets as $asset)
                        <tr data-entry-id="{{ $asset->id }}">
                            @can('asset_delete')
                                <td></td>
                            @endcan

                            <td field-key='title'>{{ $asset->title }}</td>
                            <td field-key='serial_number'>{{ $asset->serial_number }}</td>
                            <td field-key='barcode'>{{ $asset->barcode }}</td>
                            <td field-key='photo1'>@if($asset->photo1)<a href="{{ asset(env('UPLOAD_PATH').'/' . $asset->photo1) }}" target="_blank"><img src="{{ asset(env('UPLOAD_PATH').'/thumb/' . $asset->photo1) }}"/></a>@endif</td>
                            <td field-key='category'>{{ $asset->category->title ?? '' }}</td>
                            <td field-key='status'>{{ $asset->status->title ?? '' }}</td>
                            <td field-key='location'>{{ $asset->location->title ?? '' }}</td>
                            <td field-key='assigned_user'>{{ $asset->assigned_user->name ?? '' }}</td>
                            <td field-key='vendor'>{{ $asset->vendor->name ?? '' }}</td>
                            <td field-key='purchase_price'>{{ $asset->purchase_price }}</td>
                            <td field-key='warranty'>{{ $asset->warranty }}</td>

                            <td field-key='depreciation'>{{ $netprice }}</td>

                            <td>
```

How can This be achieved?

Comment: how your blade-template `admin.assets.index` looks like?

Comment: Didn't got it. Seems calculation is already done in controller. You  are only returning the netprice, you are not going to view in this?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski i wanted to return the value in a table in the index blade

Comment: @KamalPaliwal i dnt get it, i am trying to get the data to my view from the controller, so how do i achieve that?

Comment: You want to send price, dep, netprice to the admin.assets.index view?

Comment: @KamalPaliwal yes i want to send price, dep and netprice to that index view

Comment: Check my answer, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a GET request instead of a POST for your route. It should look like this:

```
Route::get('assets_depreciation', ['uses' => 'Admin\AssetsController@depreciation', 
'as' => 'assets.depreciation']);
```

Laravel's documentation gives you correct usage examples of their framework components, you can check it out here: [Laravel/Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to send the `price`, `dep` and `netprice` to the `admin.assets.index` view then you can use this:

```
public function depreciation()
{
    $assets = Asset::all();

    $price = DB::table('assets')
            ->where('category_id', 1)
            ->sum('purchase_price');
    $dep = $price * 0.3333;
    $netprice = $price - $dep;

    return view('admin.assets.index')->with(['price' => $price,'dep' => $dep, 'netprice' => $netprice]);    
}
```

Then you can use these variables in you view file `{{ $price }}, {{ $dep }}, {{ $netprice }}`

Comment: Undefined variable: netprice (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Fixed\resources\views\admin\assets\index.blade.php), this is what i am getting

Comment: Show that code where you are using $netprice and are you able to access $price and $dep in view now?

Comment: Posted where i am using netprice and no, i cannot access the price and dep still

Answer (score 0):

You need to create file `index.blade.php` in `your_project/resources/views/admin/assets/` with html-blade content e.g:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>my page</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Price: {{ $price }}</div>
        <div>Dep: {{ $dep }}</div>
        <div>Net price: {{ $netprice }}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views). And remove first `return` statement and change last return to

```
return view('admin.assets.index', compact('price','dep','netprice'));
```

Comment: i have tried this before, i keep getting unidentified variable error

Comment: try again (using above updated example) and put detailet error

Comment: Undefined variable: netprice (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Fixed\resources\views\admin\assets\index.blade.php)

Comment: Could it be a route issue?

Comment: @carrany do you remove first `return` statement and change cecond as I describe in the bottom of my answer after update ?